# Counting unique values in an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, unique-array

It's been asked before, I know, but I really don't know why my code isn't working. I'm trying to figure out how many unique values are in an undefined array. (i.e. {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7} should return a value of 5. This is what I have so far:

```
public static int numUnique(double[] list) {
    int counter = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
            if(list[i] != list[j])
                counter ++;
        }
    }
    
    
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: HashMap is really good for this if the value is already inside the HashMap than count it's value up otherwise create a new entry. Then check how many of the keys have value 1

Comment: new HashSet(Arrays.asList(list)).size()

Comment: Please don't use Sets to solve what is obviously homework.

Comment: @PetterFriberg, suggested answer refers to javascript not java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the array is sorted, you should only be checking if each element is not equal to the element immediately after it. The counter should also be initialized to `1` since if all elements are the same, the number of unique elements is `1`. We also need to add a check for a `null` or empty array, for which the result is `0`. (If it isn't sorted, you could use `Arrays.sort` to sort it, but that is not the fastest method.)

```
public static int numUnique(double[] list) {
    if(list == null || list.length == 0) return 0;
    int counter = 1;
    
   for(int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)
       if(list[i - 1] != list[i]) ++counter;
    
    
    return counter;
}
```

Alternate methods include using `Stream#distinct` or a `Set`, which do not rely on order<sup>*</sup>.

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.stream(array).distinct().count());
```

or

```
System.out.println(java.util.stream.IntStream.of(array).distinct().count());
```

---

<sup>* [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) implementation provides you with predictable iteration order.</sup>

Comment: why does this works? when you just check the one after it?

Comment: @Alex It is assumed that the array is sorted.

Comment: I doubt that would work with `[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]`. The array is not said to be sorted.

Comment: @iota also OP doesn't mentioned that it is sorted

Comment: @Alex I've added an alternate method, in any case.

Comment: @iota nice as a one liner. Have to try this

Comment: I should have mentioned, it is sorted. Thank you so much everyone, I've been scratching my head for hours, just started programming so the logic gets past me almost every time.

Answer (score 2):

If the input array is sorted as in your example, you do not need a nested loop:

```java
public static int numUnique (double[] list) {
    if (null == list || 0 == list.length) {
        return 0;
    }
    int counter = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] != list[i - 1]) {
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    
    
    return counter;
}
```

---

It is possible to use Stream API, functions `distinct` and `count` to achieve the same result (input array does not need to be sorted then):

```java
public static int numUniqueStream (double ... list) {
    if (null == list) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (int) Arrays.stream(list).distinct().count();
}
```

Comment: And if the array is not sorted...?

Comment: @Matthieu, it doesn't matter -- all of this is covered in iota's answer.  I type a way too slow.